# R Shinydashboard remove empty border around graphics

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard, spacing

I'm using `ggplot2` to create graphics and embed them into a `shinydashboard`. The goal is to have everything as "transparent" as possible, which involves setting the background in `theme` as well as `renderPlot` to the same HEX code as the bacground of the dashboard:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(ggplot2)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "Dashboard"),
  dashboardSidebar(),
  dashboardBody(
    column(4, plotOutput("plot")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$plot <- renderPlot({
    ggplot(mpg, aes(displ, hwy, colour = class)) + 
      geom_point() +
      theme(plot.background = element_rect(fill = "#ECF0F5"))
  }, bg="transparent")
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

This produces the following output, which, however, has a very thin white space border around 3 sides of the graphics as below (I zoomed in and changed the white space to red for visibility. In the actual output it is white).

[image]

How can I eliminate this empty space?